# JDBC SQL Server Database Migrations

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, migration, database

I'm working on a Java web application (Adobe Flex front-end, JPA/Hibernate/BlazeDS/Spring MVC backend) and will soon reach the point where I can no longer wipe the database and regenerate it.

What's the best approach for handling changes to the DB schema? The production and test databases are SQL Server 2005, dev's use MySQL, and unit tests run against an HSQLDB in-memory database. I'm fine with having dev machines continue to wipe and reload the DB from sample data using Hibernate to regenerate the tables. However, for a production deploy the DBA would like to have a DDL script that he can manually execute.

So, my ideal solution would be one where I can write Rails-style migrations, execute them against the test servers, and after verifying that they work be able to write out SQL Server DDL that the DBA can execute on the production servers (and which has already been validated to work agains the test servers).

What's a good tool for this? Should I be writing the DDL manually (and just let dev machines use Hibernate to regenerate the DB)? Can I use a tool like migrate4j (which seems to have limited support for SQL Server, if at all)?

I'm also looking to integrate DB manipulation scripts into this process (for example, converting a "Name" field into a "First Name", "Last Name" field via a JDBC script that splits all the existing strings).

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the best approach for handling changes to the DB schema?

**Idempotent [change scripts](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/02/versioning-databases-change-scripts.aspx)** with a version table (and a tool to apply all the change scripts with a number greater than the version currently stored in the version table). Also check the mentioned post [Bulletproof Sql Change Scripts Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA Views](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/07/05/bulletproofsqlchangescriptsusinginformation_schemaviews.aspx).

To implement this, you could roll out your own solutions or use existing tools like [DbUpdater](http://www.tewari.info/dbupdater/) (mentioned in the comments of [change scripts](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/02/versioning-databases-change-scripts.aspx)), [LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [dbdeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/). The later has my preference.

Comment: This is perfect. LiquiBase is the exact tool I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I depend on hibernate to create whatever it needs on the production server. There's no risk of losing data because it never removes anything: it only adds what is missing.

On the current project, we have established a convention by which any feature which requires a change in the database (schema or data) is required to provide it's own DDL/DML snippets, meaning that all we need to do is to aggregate the snippets into a single script and execute it to get production up to date. None of this works on a very large scale (order of snippets becomes critical, not everyone follows the convention etc.), but in a small team and an iterative process it works just fine.